# autocomplete in App Framework using AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, appframework

How to implement Auto Complete Text Box in App Framework Using AngularJS,
Auto Complete Method gives error undefined

The following code throws an error when using AppFramework:

```
$scope.complete = function () { 
  console.log($scope.availableTags); 
  $("#tags").autocomplete({ source: $scope.availableTags }); 
};
```

> Error autoComplete method is undefined

Comment: Please tell us what you have tried before or some more information that can be added to your question

Comment: The below code worked well in Web Application but in Mobile Application using AppFramework gives the Error autoComplete method is undefined `code` $scope.complete = function () {
        console.log($scope.availableTags);
        $("#tags").autocomplete({
            source: $scope.availableTags
        });
    };`code`

Comment: in the future, please edit the question to include relevant code or error messages, rather than using comments.  Code blocks posted in comments lose their formatting and become difficult to interpret.

Comment: based on the code you provided, it appears as though you are trying to mix angular and jquery, which isn't the best approach.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `ng-autocomplete`. I have provided a simple example as follows:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="Test">
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"href="style.css">

    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?libraries=places&sensor=false"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.0.8/angular.js"></script>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
    <script src="ngAutocomplete.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
<div ng-controller="TestCtrl">

<form id="form" role="form">

    <div class="form-group move-down">
        <label for="Autocomplete">Generic Autocomplete</label>
        <input type="text" id="Autocomplete" class="form-control" ng-autocomplete="result1" details="details1" options="options1"/>
    </div>
</form>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

You can also use Angucomplete. Find it here: http://ghiden.github.io/angucomplete-alt/